# How do I change either the text in the views data export CSV button or the button completely

Tags: views

I have a view that exports data, so the csv button is displayed.  I want the button to read "Export" instead of CSV - how can I change the text that displays on that button or display a different button completely?

Comment: If you are never planning on upgrading this module, those images are stored in the sites/all/modules/views_data_export/images folder. I'm sure you can edit or upload your own here; just keep the name the same and it should work fine. If, however, you do want to be able to update, you may consider writing your own custom module that piggybacks off of this one.

Comment: Thank you emijayne - I am sure I will update that mod at some point, but I can just keep the gif handy should i ever overwrite.  I was looking for a quick fix instead of putting a module together.  I should have thought of this - thanks very much!!!!